# Testing a Rails ApplicationController method with rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec-rails

Just having trouble figuring out how to test an action that utilizes a private ApplicationController method. To explain:

A User has and belongs to many Organisations (through Roles), and vice versa. An Organisation has a bunch of related entities, but in the app a user is only dealing with a single Organisation at a time, so for all of my controller methods I want to scope with a current organisation. So in my ApplicationController:

```
private

# Returns the organisation that is being operated on in this session.
def current_org
  # Get the org id from the session. If it doesn't exist, or that org is no longer operable by the current user,
  # find an appropriate one and return that.
  if (!session[:current_organisation_id] || !current_user.organisations.where(['organisations.id = ?', session[:current_organisation_id]]).first)
    # If an org doesn't exist for this user, all hope is lost, just go to the home page
    redirect_to '/' if (!current_user.organisations.first)
    # Otherwise set the session with the new org
    session[:current_organisation_id] = current_user.organisations.first.id;
  end
  # Return the current org!
  current_user.organisations.first
end
```

First things first, I don't know if this is the best way to scope. I'd love some elegant default_scope thing, but with the use of session variables this seems problematic. Anyway, the above let's me do this in controllers:

```
class HousesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @houses = current_org.houses
  end
end
```

So now I want to use rspec to test my controllers. How can I make sure the current_org method can be called and returns one of the factory_girl Organisation models so that I can write the spec. I'm just confused at how best to bring the factory, spec, action and AppControlled method together.